# Creating Subfolders in VB2010?

Tags: vba

I'm in the position of needing to make a bunch of folders for my PC so I decided to turn it in to a coding task. I've managed to make it so the user types in the location they want the folders to go into as well as each line of the other text box being the title for a new folder.

Here's the problem. I ideally would like to put multiple folders inside each folder without running the program again. The textbox would look something like this and would result in file 1,2 in folderA and file 3,4 in folderB;

FolderA

File 1

File 2

FolderB

File 3

File 4

Here is the code I've done so far.

```
Dim Address As String = TextBox1.Text

    For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Address + (RichTextBox1.Lines(i)))
    Next
```

Do you know what I would have to add to my code so that it includes sub-folders? 
(I haven't been learning long so I'm sorry if the answer is really obvious.)

Comment: which application are you doing this in? MS Access, MS Excel, or Word?

Comment: Personally, I use `MKDir()` function with a full path description, it seems to be pretty easy to use! You can get the present Path of a Workbook (Excel), simply like this `ThisWorkBook.Path` and then just add the name of your sub folder after it with `& "SubFolder name\"`

If you could display a bit more clearly what your input look like, I'll do a proper answer to explain how to use it in your case! ;)

Comment: MKDir is certainly the way to go.  The code I provided below provides a bit more flexibility for the base directory vs ThisWorkbook.Path and I "think" the code should work in any applications' VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@punintentional

The code below will do exactly what you asked for. You HAVE to make sure you have a reference set to the Microsoft Office Object Library. You do this by going to Tools>References and find the appropriate on.  I designed the below code with Microsoft Office 12 Object Library.  If you are using Office 2010, I think the Reference will be for Microsoft Office 14 Object Library.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DirectorySelect()
    Dim diaFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim blDirSelected As Boolean
    Dim strBaseDirectory As String
    Dim strA_Dir As String
    Dim StrB_Dir As String

'   set up a MS Office file dialog box to select a folder/directory
    Set diaFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With diaFileDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False ' user may only select one base folder
        .Title = "Select the base director"  ' title of the dialog box

        blDirSelected = .Show  ' the .show method will return false if the user does not select a directory


        If blDirSelected = True Then   ' a directory was selected

            strBaseDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)  ' put the directory into a variable
            strBaseDirectory = strBaseDirectory & "\"  ' the returned directory needs a trailing backslash

'           These steps will jump to the other sub procedure to make the desired folders
            MakeNewDir _
                BaseDirectory:=strBaseDirectory, _
                AddDirectory:="FolderA"

            strA_Dir = strBaseDirectory & "FolderA" & "\"

            MakeNewDir _
                BaseDirectory:=strA_Dir, _
                AddDirectory:="Folder1"
            MakeNewDir _
                BaseDirectory:=strA_Dir, _
                AddDirectory:="Folder2"

            MakeNewDir _
                BaseDirectory:=strBaseDirectory, _
                AddDirectory:="FolderB"

            StrB_Dir = strBaseDirectory & "FolderB" & "\"

            MakeNewDir _
                BaseDirectory:=StrB_Dir, _
                AddDirectory:="Folder3"
            MakeNewDir _
                BaseDirectory:=StrB_Dir, _
                AddDirectory:="Folder4"

        End If
    End With


End Sub

Public Sub MakeNewDir(ByVal BaseDirectory As String, ByVal AddDirectory As String)
    If Dir(BaseDirectory, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MkDir BaseDirectory
    End If
    If Right(BaseDirectory, 1) <> "\" Then
        BaseDirectory = BaseDirectory & "\"
    End If
    MkDir BaseDirectory & AddDirectory
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response:D. I've looked at Tools but as you can see (tinyurl.com/p8kdk8w) References isn't there. I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express, is that the reason it's no there?

Comment: @punintentional I'm sorry I've never used VB 2010 Express so I cannot help.  The above code was written in MS Excel Visual Basic Editor. Maybe someone else can give some input where to set references in VB 2010 Express or how to late bind to FileDialog